# c# wpf importing excel performance

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, office-interop

I'm importing a large excel file that can vary in length (250+ columns * 100,000 rows), it holds columns of data, where amount of columns and their names can change, rows are also variable but they are the values.

I'm using Interop to pull the data into a datatable which is bound to a datagrid, however I'm importing each row individually and it can take 25+ minutes to complete for larger files.

```
    public Task<DataTable> ParseExcel(string filePath)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            var excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.Item[1];

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

            DataTable sessiondt = new DataTable();

            object[,] value = excelRange.Value;

            int columnsCount = value.GetLength(1);
            for (var colCnt = 1; colCnt <= columnsCount; colCnt++)
            {
                sessiondt.Columns.Add((string)value[1, colCnt], typeof(string));
            }

            int rowsCount = value.GetLength(0);
            for (var rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= rowsCount; rowCnt++)
            {
                var dataRow = sessiondt.NewRow();
                for (var colCnt = 1; colCnt <= columnsCount; colCnt++)
                {
                    dataRow[colCnt - 1] = value[rowCnt, colCnt];
                }
                sessiondt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            excelBook.Close(true);
            excelApp.Quit();

            return sessiondt;
        });  
    }
```

Rather than inserting each row individually, it would probably be faster to put it all into a List of a custom object that can be data bound. But I'm unsure of how to do this.

Also, I want to bind the columns in a way which i don't have to code in the column names in advance. I'll be trying to display these in graphs and being able to populate the column names into a Combobox automatically would be allot easier.

Thank you in advance, I am new to c# and wpf and still learning.

Comment: I would avoid using Excel.Interop as often as I can. It's slow and requires Excel to be installed whereever you want to use your software. If you have Excel files in OpenXml format (.xlsx) it's not that bad to parse them without Excel (it are just zip-files with xml-files inside it). If you need to support older versions of Excel, even for that there are libraries without Excel.Interop. I don't know which ones are good nowadays (the last time I parsed .xls/.xlsx is more than 5 years ago), but you should try to find an alternative without Excel.Interop, e.g. http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interop has some specific uses, but if you just want to get the data from an Excel file, Interop is probably the slowest and most cumbersome way to go.

An Excel file, either .xls or .xlsx can be treated and accessed just like a database.

As long as you have data in rows and columns in your worksheets, you can open an `OleDb` connection to it and run queries against it.

The Sheet names take the place of the table name and if you have column headings in the first row of your sheet, those are the field names.

You just need the proper connection string:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

One of the 'watch-outs' with this method of retrieving your data is that data types are automatically assigned based on the first few entries in each column.  You cannot override this behavior (you used to be able to, but no longer).  A time where this might cause a problem is if you have alpha-numerics in a column, and the first dozen or so entries are all numbers.  This column will then be automatically assigned as a numeric type.  If you have data in later rows of this column that are mixed alpha-numeric or straight text, these entries will be ignored (not imported) because they don't match the data type that was initially assigned.

The only good way around that is to programmatically unzip and parse out the contents of the xml files.

If you have consistent data throughout, then this isn't an issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start to do some research into OleDb. The first two rows of each column are name and units then its all numeric so this should be fine. Would you be able to give a simple example of how to implement? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way how you can do this, fast and straightforward, by using [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) library:

```
public Task<DataTable> ParseExcel(string filePath)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ExcelFile excelBook = ExcelFile.Load(filePath);
        ExcelWorksheet excelSheet = excelBook.Worksheets[0];

        CreateDataTableOptions options = new CreateDataTableOptions();
        return excelSheet.CreateDataTable(options);
    });
}
```

Also check [this DataTable from Sheet example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-create-datatable-from-excel/503).